# Keeping streaming on in ArcMap when switching editing tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, digitizing

I have this problem constantly, because I digitize for work. No one there has figured this out and I was wondering if someone can tell me how to do this, because I'm tired of constantly hitting F8 and it sometimes not even switching to streaming when I click it. I need to be able to keep streaming on when switching tools such as cut polygons, reshape features, and creating features. Anyone know?

I know there is a method to do this, because one of the computers we have does this, but I want to do it on the other ones as well, and I want to know how to turn it off on that computer when I need to.

Answer (score 2):

I tried using #5 as found in the [Streaming](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000006m000000.htm) help:

> 5. If you click the map, streaming is suspended, so you can switch among
>      construction methods, such as straight or curved, and also click
>      buttons, menus, and other user interface elements. Click the map again
>      to start streaming.

and it works fine.  And I didn't have to hit F8 each time.  Are you saying #5 doesn't work for you?

Otherwise, I can't think of another way to suspend streaming in order to click a button on a toolbar without hitting F8.

You also might play around with the streaming tolerance to see if that affects anything, although I doubt it will in this particular case.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean with #5..

Comment: Did you go to the link and read the #5 option or point?  If so, did you try it?  If I'm not being clear, I can try to expound or add screenshots.

Comment: Wait a sec, I think I misread what you are attempting to do.  You want to be able to manipulate a feature that is already created using the stream mode?

Comment: O point #5. I use that all the time. That's not my problem, though. I am not trying to switch tools in middle of using one, it's in between editing different polygons. For example: I just cut out a section of a polygon, deleted it and now I click the edit tool and click on a different polygon and I want to use the reshape tool, so I click on the reshape tool but streaming is now off, so I have to hit F8 to use streaming with the reshape tool but I'd like streaming to just stay on automatically. Does that example make sense?

Comment: Yep, that makes good sense. I just didn't interpret your OP that way. Sorry.  I don't think there is a way to do that in the current version of ArcMap.  I don't use stream mode normally since it adds too many vertices to features for my taste, and can make some geoprocessing tools work much harder or even crash.  You might be hosed until a new version comes out.

Comment: I know there is a way to do this, though, because one of the computers is set to do it this way. But I can't figure out how to not do it on that computer, or how to do it on the other computers. And I love/need streaming because we do tree canopy and land use covers which have areas where we aren't allowed to have straight edges